# Question using github API

Tags: ruby, github, sinatra, github-api

I'm using the Github API for a personal side project (more specifically, [Octokit](https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit/) as a Ruby wrapper for it), and am running into a little trouble. I can't seem to figure out how to see the number of commits/merged pushes a repo has had.

I see in the [Repos section of the Github V2 API](http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html) (in *show repo information*), it shows `pushed_at`, which is the latest push.

If I were to want to retrieve the last 5 or so commits/merged pushes, do you know how I could go about doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look into the [Commits API](http://develop.github.com/p/commits.html), rather than the Repository API.